# How can I write roman numbers in MathJax?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I need to write roman numbers in MathJax. I've tried almost every way. But, then I decided to copy the symbol itself. But it looks very ugly.

For example,

> $$\displaystyle \mathcal {D}^{{\left(II \right)}}_n $$

I tried LaTex syntax. `\rom`. But, unfortunately it doesn`t work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do you mean `\mathrm{IX}` perhaps? $\mathrm{IX}$?

There's a reason why the font family is called "Roman".

Comment: Or the alternative but more archaic `{\rm IX}`.